# Convert categorical values to columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert categorical rows to separate columns while keeping the primary keys in the data.

In the data, all the useful attributes live in 2 columns (attribute_name and attribute_value). I want to convert the rows in attribute_name to separate columns and populate them with the corresponding data from attribute_value column (like shown in the image below).

Note: Not all the part_ids have the same attribute names or have them populated. After the transformation, some part_ids will have missing values in the new columns.

I tried the pandas unstack() and pivot() functions but they also convert platform_id and part_id values to columns.

The below code came closest to my requirement but it created duplicated columns for each part_id and I couldn't do this transformation while keeping my primary keys like platform_id and part_id:

```
df[['attribute_name', attribute_value']].set_index('attribute_name').T.rename_axis(None axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Adding the code to re-create the dataframe:

```
data = {'Platform_id':[4356, 4356, 4356, 23675, 23675, 23675, 772, 772],\

    'part_id':['XCVT43', 'XCVT43', 'XCVT43', 'TT3344', 'TT3344', 'TT3344', 'GHTYW2', 'GHTYW2'], \

    'class_id':['PROCESSOR', 'PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR','PROCESSOR',], \

    'attribute_name': ['Vendor_name', 'Cache', 'Clock-speed', 'Vendor_name', 'Model_name', 'Clock-speed', 'Vendor_name', 'Cache'], \

    'attribute_value': ['Intel', '4', '3.1', 'Intel', '4500U', '2.3', None, '4']}



df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: data transformation before and after]

Comment: please show a dataframe. We need a dataframe to try solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
vendors=df['attribute_name'].unique()
df2=pd.concat([df.set_index(['Platform_id','part_id','class_id']).groupby('attribute_name')['attribute_value'].get_group(key) for key in vendors],axis=1)
df2.columns=vendors
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df2)



   Platform_id part_id   class_id Vendor_name Cache Clock-speed Model_name
0          772  GHTYW2  PROCESSOR        None     4         NaN        NaN
1         4356  XCVT43  PROCESSOR       Intel     4         3.1        NaN
2        23675  TT3344  PROCESSOR       Intel   NaN         2.3      4500U
```

Comment: brilliant! I wouldn't been able to figure this out. Your code can be used in so many of my other projects.

Comment: I am glad to help you!